# lightning design on VF page for Fieldset

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

We have an existing VF page where FIELDSETS is been used. FIELDSET has multiple fields like Text,Textarea,checkbox,richtext etc.
We have to apply lightning stye using Lightning desgin system but since the fields are comming dynamically .
We are unable to render styles on individual fields . Is there any solution on this ?

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="1" showHeader="true" 
            collapsible="false" rendered="{!layoutType == 1}">

            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.INFO__c.FieldSets.Marketing_Information}" var="field">
                <apex:inputField value="{!objInteraction[field]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```